# JPQL query error

Tags: postgresql, jpa, jpql

Considering following correct query

```
select _.* from _misc._lang__ _ where _.id > 10 order by _.id asc limit 1 offset 0
```

Now I tried to make the JPQL query like this

```
select l from _misc._lang__ l where l.id > :arg order by l.id asc limit 1 offset 0
```

And the error(EclipseLink)

```
The ORDER BY clause has 'l.id ASC ' and 'limit ' that are not separated by a comma.
```

It seems eclipse link got the `limit` as column name rather than the keyword, now how can I fix it?
Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you learn the syntax of JPQL: it uses class names and not table names, it doesn't use .*, and it doesn't have limit and offset clauses. In short it's a different language from SQL, and you have to learn it.

Comment: @JBNizet sorry, typo :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"limit" is not reconized. You can use `yourQuery.setMaxresults` method instead like so :

```
result=em.createQuery("select l.* from _misc._lang__ l where l.id > :arg order by l.id asc").setParameter("arg", yourArg).setMaxResults(2).getResultList()
```